# Cambiar el nombre de un archivo en mi servidor local

Tags: php, html, fileupload

¿Cómo puedo hacer, si quiero cambiar el nombre a un archivo que ya subí a mi localhost?.

Estoy utilizando `Xampp` y cuento con el nombre del archivo al que le quiero asignar un nombre nuevo, pero al momento de usar el **rename** no me hace ningun cambio.

El código:

```
$carpeta_destino = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/TestPHP/MVC/Contenidos/';

$file_url = uniqid() . $nombre_ruta;
rename(   $nombre_ruta,     $file_url);
        
$ruta_internet = 'localhost/TestPHP/MVC/Contenidos/' . $file_url;
```

Mi variable `$nombre_ruta` es simplemente el nombre del archivo que está ya subido en mi servidor, y el `$file_url` es el nombre que le quiero dar a mi archivo, ya que lo quiero hacer único.

Cabe recalcar que esto lo mando a llamar desde un *controlador*, por lo que la carpeta en donde se encuentra el archivo que quiero renombrar, se encuentra en una carpeta arriba (actualmente este codigo lo tengo dentro de un archivo `php` en la carpeta *controlador*, y la carpeta que contiene a *controlador* es `MVC`, la misma que sale en la variable `$carpeta_destino`).

Comment: Puede estar fallando por distintas razones, me parece que puede ser porque la ruta al archivo no es correcto; si esta función `rename()` falla retornara falso, te sugiero que hagas un `print_r()` sobre su salida, también, sobre la variable `$nombre_ruta`

Comment: @Josbert Muchas gracias! Tenia razón, la ruta que estaba tomando no era la correcta, simplemente le faltaba un slash, la corregí y me funcionó con normalidad, aprecio mucho que se tomara el tiempo de hacerme ver mi error :)

Comment: Perfecto amigo, todo un gusto..!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias al comentario de Josbert pude darme cuenta que estaba ingresando mal la ruta, tengan en cuenta que el **rename** empieza desde el directorio en el que se está llamando, por lo cual tienes que saber en donde está ubicado el archivo que quieres renombrar dentro de tu servidor, en mi caso tuve que acceder a la carpeta padre con un `../` y ya entrar a la carpeta en donde se encontraba mi archivo **Contenidos**, no olviden poner los slash correctos ya que en un principio no me funcionó debido a que me faltó uno, gracias a todos, espero que les pueda ser de utilidad en algún momento.

```
rename("../Contenidos/" . $nombre_ruta, "../Contenidos/" . $nom_nuevo);
```